# Linguistic umbrella term for things and relations between things

Tags: terminology

Is there an established term in linguistics which is a hypernym of both 'things' (e.g. entities; categories of entities; actions; ...), and the relationships between them?

Intuitively, I would assume that maybe 'concepts' would work.
I can have a (mental) concept of 'dog' (category), a mental concept of a specific entity, e.g. 'Mike', a concept of 'dancing' (action), and a concept of relations, e.g. 'is_a' as in 'Mike is_a Dog', or 'has_owner' as in 'Mike has_owner Karl'.

Framed differently, I am interested in whether there is a linguistic term which covers subject, predicate and object in a semantic triple <s,p,o>.

Is 'concept' the right choice here, or is there another term used in scholarly contexts which encompasses both things/actions and relations between those?

Comment: There is the notion of a "content word" vs. "function word", which is roughly the distinction between nouns/verbs/adjectives/proper names one the one hand and conjunctions/articles/prepositions and the like on the other hand. But this is a generalization of word categories and isn't normally used in extension to complex expressions, and it is just a static category about the lexical status of the word without taking into account its grammatical role in the sentence.

Comment: In the terminology of semantics, properties of individuals (*is-a-dog, dances, is-red*) and relations between individuals (*loves, has-owner, lies-between-and*) are summarized under the term "predicates", but this doesn't include individual entities (*Mike, the president of the US*) and quantified expressions (*a dog*, *all dogs*). "Predicate" here is not to be confused with the syntactic meaning of "predicate" which is usually taken to be the verb of a sentence, not the subject or object.

Comment: Linguistics doesn't have that term because not all the languages operate with them. What looks like 3 elements in _[I] [am a] [man]_ from your point of view is treated quite differently in, say, Turkish where this phrase is _bir adamım_ where _bir_ means the same as English ‘a’ and _adamım_ ‘am man’.

Comment: Any entity (_Bill Smith, a piece of pie, the officer of the day_) can appear as a  predicate. Any verb or adjective can appear as a predicate. Sounds like you mean "predicate".

Comment: @jlawler You mean any entity can appear as a subject or object? Or what would be an example where an individual occurs as a predicate (in the syntactic sense)?

Comment: _This man is John Smith_, for instance. Put a form of _be_ in front of it, and an article as needed, and any noun phrase (not just an individual noun) can be a predicate. It's known as a "predicate noun" or "predicate nominal". _Predicate,_ however, isn't a syntactic term; it's from [logic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf), not grammar. People often confuse the two, but they're handled on different levels in linguistics.

Comment: @jlalwer Oh, right. But the usage of the term "predicate" in syntax is a different one than in logic: In a sentence like "The dog is sleeping", both "dog" and "is sleeping" are predicates in the logical sense, but only "is sleeping" would be considered a (or "the") predicate in the syntactic sense, in distinction to the subject of the sentence, or am I mistaken?

Comment: I wouldn't use "predicate" when speaking of syntax. "Verb Phrase" is the closest I'd come, or "Matrix Verb" if wanted to pick out a particular one. (Though, being honest, I probly do, sometimes, but it's sloppy and not defined -- I would just mean whatever chunk of syntax would be crunched into one Predicate in a logical description, like the treatment of _Marie of Roumania_ in the logistification of Dorothy Parker's poem on the last page of the [Logic Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf).)

Comment: What I gather from this discussion is that there isn't really a linguistic term for what I'm looking for. I guess I will just settle for 'concept' to include everything, and define it this way in my context.